# Bash - Diff change header (name of files)

Tags: bash, shell, diff

I am creating .patch file from diff `diff -u $i /tmp/b/${i#/tmp/a/} > /tmp/patch/$j.patch` and I want to ask how can I change the names of files in header of each patch file. Now I have `/tmp/a/...` and I want `a/...` Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `sed` or such to change the text in each patch file. And then use `diff` to verify the changes. And if you get it wrong, you get to figure out the output of diff applied to diff output, what fun :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no direct option for this in `diff`. When applying your diff with [patch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) use `-p <num>` option to strip the paths. In your case `-p2` would give the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand, but if you were just to start your process while "sitting" at /tmp
providing `diff` relative path - wouldn't it just work?  Seems to work for me
(p.s. didn't know what your outer loop or the diff between $i & $j are, so used my own example with a FLAT tree)

```bsh
cd /tmp
for i in a/*; do 
  diff -u "${i}" "b/${i#a/}" > "/tmp/patch/${i#a/}.patch"
done
```